# Canceling file dialog prompted the excel to open excel log file

Tags: excel, vba

I hope all of you are having a good day. I have a problem with my code here. The code here will display a file dialog and ask the user the choose the file, and it worked out great. My problem is that, when it display the file dialog, instead of choosing the folder that I want, I want to click cancel. But when I click on cancel, there will be a runtime error saying that, "The subscript is out or range." and it will open an excel file with title ts-event.log

So, I tried to overcome this problem by using error handling, On Error GoTo . So instead of the default message box from VBA, I will get a msgbox that said, "You cancelled the action." but I still get that ts-event.log excel file open. How do I avoid this? Can someone help me. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub UploadData()

Dim SummWb As Workbook
Dim SceWb As Workbook

'Get folder containing files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    myFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    'Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo Error_handler
End With

If Right(myFolderName, 1) <> "\" Then myFolderName = myFolderName & "\"
    'Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Set SummWb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Get source files and append to output file
    mySceFileName = Dir(myFolderName & "*.*")

        Do While mySceFileName <> "" 'Stop once all files found
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & mySceFileName
            Set SceWb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderName & mySceFileName) 'Open file found
                With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B1").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B2").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C7").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D7").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C8").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D8").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C9").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D9").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SummWb.Sheets("Upload Survey").Range("C8").Value
                End With
            SceWb.Close (False) 'Close Workbook
            mySceFileName = Dir

       Loop
Error_handler:
MsgBox ("You cancelled the action.")

MsgBox ("Upload complete.")

'Settings and save output file
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
SummWb.Activate
SummWb.Save 'save automaticallly
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: /have you tried application.displayalerts = false ?

Comment: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/vba-select-folder-with-msoFileDialogFolderPicker/ shows how to check the user didn't cancel

Comment: Hi @Jeeped I've tried but still the same

Comment: hi @TimWilliams I follow the step from the link that you gave me, still the same, it will open the excel log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cancel doesn't mean that it's an error

```
Sub UploadData()

Dim SummWb As Workbook
Dim SceWb As Workbook
Dim myFolderName As String
Dim oldstatusbar As Boolean
Dim mySceFileName As String

On Error GoTo Error_handler
'Get folder containing files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        myFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
      Else 'You clicked cancel
        GoTo Cancel_handler
    End If
End With

If Right(myFolderName, 1) <> "\" Then myFolderName = myFolderName & "\"
   'Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    oldstatusbar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Set SummWb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Get source files and append to output file
    mySceFileName = Dir(myFolderName & "*.*")

        Do While mySceFileName <> "" 'Stop once all files found
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & mySceFileName
            Set SceWb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderName & mySceFileName) 'Open file found
                With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B1").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B2").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C7").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D7").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C8").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D8").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C9").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D9").Value
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SummWb.Sheets("Upload Survey").Range("C8").Value
                End With
            SceWb.Close (False) 'Close Workbook
            mySceFileName = Dir

       Loop

  SummWb.Activate
  SummWb.Save 'save automaticallly
  MsgBox ("Upload complete.")
Finish:
  Application.StatusBar = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldstatusbar
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Exit Sub
Cancel_handler:
  MsgBox "You cancelled the action."
  Exit Sub
Error_handler:
  MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred."
  GoTo Finish
End Sub
```

Notice the first `Exit Sub`: This is where the program will end if no error occurs. If the cancel button is clicked it will show the msgbox and end at the second `Exit Sub`. But if an **error** occurs you bring it back with `Goto Finish` where you have all the statements to bring the application back to the initial state.

Comment: Thanks, but I have changed the code again so see what I have changed.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much on the explanation of the exit sub, that is the thing that was missing from my code. I replaced on error resume next to on error goto error_handler and added exit subs in the end of the code before end subs. it works wonderfully. thank you again for your help.